# How do you use regex to parse text across multiple lines from a log file?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a log output, summarized below. I need to parse the Final Input, which goes across multiple lines. I cannot find a regex expression that works.

```
04/10/2019 02:52:59 PM INFO: Model Details:
04/10/2019 02:53:12 PM INFO: Final Input: [  220.12134       3.7499998    75.00001     111.44428      22.500004
    37.5          73.361534  1000.709    ]
04/10/2019 02:53:12 PM INFO: Difference: [ 11.974823 647.91406 ]
04/10/2019 02:53:12 PM INFO: Number: 169
04/10/2019 02:53:12 PM INFO: Time: 13.554227686000004 seconds
```

I'd like a numpy array output:

```
[220.12134, 3.7499998, 75.00001, 111.44428, 22.50000437.5, 73.361534, 1000.709]
```

Using the following code, I can get this to work for single lines:

```
log_file_path = some_log.log
#regex = '\[(.*?)\]'
regex2 = '(Final Input: \[)(.*?)(\]|\n)'

with open(log_file_path, 'r') as file:
    all_log_file = file.read()
    a = re.findall(regex2, all_log_file)
    print(a)

file.close()
#x = list(map(float, a.split()))
```

I get the following output, which is missing the Final Input values on the next line (I can parse the output below into a numpy array):

```
[('Final Input: [', '  220.12134       3.7499998    75.00001     111.44428      22.500004', '\n')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *non-greedy* specifier, along with `re.DOTALL`, which signifies that `.` includes `\n`:

```
import re

regex2 = '(Final Input: \[.+?\])'

a = re.findall(regex2, text, re.DOTALL)
a
```

Output:

```
['Final Input: [  220.12134       3.7499998    75.00001     111.44428      22.500004\n    37.5          73.361534  1000.709    ]']
```